# how to locate a file?

Tags: java, file, location, bufferedreader

Hi I want to know how the program can locate a file.
For example. I have a class

```
    public class MiReader {

    private File file;    
    private BufferedReader bufferedReader;    

    public MiReader(String dir) {

        try {
            file= new File(dir);
            bufferedReader = new BufferedReader(new FileReader(file));

        } catch (Exception ex) {
            Logger.getLogger(MiReader.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
        }        
    }

    public void imprimir() {    
        ***
    }
}
```

I know that the file is on the project (I'm using netbeans)
project is on `C:\NetBeansProjects\Application`

file: `C:\NetBeansProjects\Application\file.txt`

so when I instance MiReader must be something like this:

```
MiReader mr = new MiReader("C:\\NetBeansProjects\\Application\\file.txt");
```

and now if I run the program from another location
for example now its on

`D:\Pograms\Application`

so the file is `D:\Pograms\Application\file.txt`

and now I have to change the way I create the class to

```
MiReader mr = new MiReader("D:\\Pograms\\Application\\file.txt");
```

I want to know how the program can locate the file just running the program,
something like

```
MiReader mr = new MiReader(program.getLocation()+"\\file.txt")
```

> Learning english :)

Comment: You should look into the concept of classpath in Java.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use System.getProperty to get the user.home, the user.dir, the classpath etc as a standard prefix for the file you are trying to open. [Here are all of the System properties](http://www-01.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/#!/ssw_i5_54/rzaha/sysprop2.htm)

ie

File f = new File (System.getProperty("user.home" + "/foo.txt"));

Comment: Thanks both answers were useful but I learned something more with that System.getProperty

Answer (score 1):

You could use relative paths. Aka

```
MiReader Mr = new MiReader("file.text");
```

This way the program will look for the file `file.text` inside the directory you run it from.